# I am getting {"message":"Page not found for GET /chat"} using a route in React Router 6.4.3

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router-dom

I am working on an Express/React app using web pack to bundle. I have two routes in my index.js file. The route to App.js is "/". I have a route to Chat.js at "chat". The route to App works and shows the test heading from / in the browser. The route to Chat gives the error {"message":"Page not found for GET /chat"} in the browser. Here is index.js:

[image: Code for project]

"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",

I have tried changing the route from <Route path='/chat'  to <Route path='chat'

I've been using react for 2 years and since the new version of react (18) and react-router-dom (6.4) I haven't been able to get a single app to work

I expected the Chat page to display in the browser and instead got {"message":"Page not found for GET /chat"}

Comment: That error seems like a server error or something to do with how page requests are handled. How are you running this app? Please also share a [mcve] of the relevant code and instructions/reproduction steps. Images of code are not accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable.

Comment: Sorry about the image the text editor was giving me errors that my code wasn't correctly formatted (first post here). Here is the repo https://github.com/Matthew-Beasley/anon-talk it can be started with npm run dev. Its running on a dead simple express server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for your server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
}

app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// If no other routes are hit, send the React app
app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next({
    status: 404,
    message: `Page not found for ${req.method} ${req.url}`,
  });
});
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500).send({
    message: err.message || JSON.stringify(err),
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log('Listening on PORT ', process.env.PORT));
```

I've run this locally using your repo and it works. I've also pushed the working changes to an example repo in GitHub (https://github.com/rsg71/react-stack-overflow).

What you needed to change was send the React app without specifying the GET / endpoint:

Previously you had:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

What you need instead is:

```
// If no other routes are hit, send the React app
app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html')));
```

Now the react-router-dom package can handle routing. Otherwise, you are relying on express for the routing of your React app which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would never have found that one